# subtract columns in data.frame using conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

What I want to do is subtract columns in data frame if condition is met. This isnt my data, but test data.

```
x<-mtcars;
x;
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         42.0  12  320 220 7.80 5.24 32.92  0  2    8    8
Mazda RX4 Wag     42.0  12  320 220 7.80 5.75 34.04  0  2    8    8
Datsun 710        45.6   8  216 186 7.70 4.64 37.22  2  2    8    2
Hornet 4 Drive    42.8  12  516 220 6.16 6.43 38.88  2  0    6    2
Hornet Sportabout 37.4  16  720 350 6.30 6.88 34.04  0  0    6    4
Valiant           36.2  12  450 210 5.52 6.92 40.44  2  0    6    2
```

Below is the code I am trying to use. I want if ncol = carb subtract ncol -2 or if ncol = gear ncol - 1

```
w <- function(x){if (x[,ncol(x)] == c("carb")) {(ncol(x)-2)} else (ncol(x)-1)};
```

output:

```
Warning message:
In if (x[, ncol(x)] == c("carb")) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I get that the this is talking about logical things, but I can figure out what the heck to do from here.

I then want to spit this into: (this is for my data, and isnt replicated in data above)

```
Subtract<- finaltable[paste(tmp), w];
```

Can someone help me get this to work?

Comment: What does `ncol = carb` mean?  `ncol` is number of columns and `carb` is a column in your dataset.  How could these every be equal?  I don't understand the rationale behind what you want to achieve.

Comment: Well, I thought, I was asking if last column == carb then do that. If that isnt right, how do you do that then?

Comment: You need to access `names(x)[ncol(x)]` or `tail(names(x),1)` to check against the last column name. This is an unusual way of going about column selecting though. What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a data set that I add new data everyday. I add three or two new columns of data each day. Digit, dead, carried or digit, dead. I need the digit info to help automate my code. So if do I suggested then I can get the last digit column

Comment: This seems to work: function(x){if (tail(names(x),1) == c("carb")) {(ncol(x)-2)} else (ncol(x)-1)}

Comment: @ thelatemail, I never heard of this way you just suggested.

Comment: @ thelatemail, can you answer question, so I can vote and get give you stuff?

Comment: You want find out if the last column is named "carb" or not?  Then, if it is, subtract 2 from the number of columns in the data frame (i.e. `11 - 2`) and if it is not, subtract 1 from the number of columns (i.e. `11 - 1`)?

Comment: @ frank, well the last bit would be 10-1, thus the answer is always 9. Seems simple, but couldnt for the life of me get it. Call me crazy, but couldnt. I also needed it to be automated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In light of the comments, you need to use one of either:

```
names(x)[ncol(x)] # [1] "carb"
tail(names(x),1)  # [1] "carb"
```

to check against the last column name. As opposed to:

```
x[,ncol(x)]
#[1] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 4 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 2 1 1 2 2 4 2 1 2 2 4 6 8 2
```

...which will actually return the contents of the last column rather than the column name.